# If $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R) $ then $\phi_{t}(x)=\frac{1}{t} \phi(x/t)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $\phi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a function; and define 
$$\phi_{t}(x):=\frac{1}{t}\phi (x/t), (t>0).$$

We note that, if $\phi\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ then $\phi_{t}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R);$ in fact, we have,  $\|\phi \|_{L^{1}}= \|\phi_{t}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}.$

Consider the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), 
$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)= \{f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R): \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} (1+|x|)^{m} |\partial^{n} f(x) |< \infty, \forall m, n \in \mathbb N \} $

**My Question is**: (1) Suppose $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R).$ Is it true that, $\phi_{t}\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$ (Take any fix $t>0$)? (2) If answer in (1) is negative, then is it possible to find some non-zero $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\phi_{t}$ is also in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$?

> **My Little attempt**: I think, If $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R),$ then $\phi_{t}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R);$ as composition of differentiable functions is differentiable and $\partial^{n}\phi_{t}(x)= \frac{1}{t}\partial^{n}\phi(x/t)= \frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \partial^{n} \phi(x/t),$...

Thanks,

Comment: The answer is "yes" and your attempt is starting out in the right way. Now just keep estimating. For example, suppose $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} (1+|x|)^{m} |\partial^{n} \phi(x) | = C_{m,n} < \infty$. Can you express $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} (1+|x|)^{m} |\partial^{n} \phi_t(x) |$ in terms of $C_{m,n}$ and $t$?

Comment: @prof. HE; thanks; can you give a little more hint; (see, $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}(1+|x|)^{m}|\partial^{n}\phi_{t}(x)|= \frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R}(1+|x|)^{m}|\partial^{n}\phi(x/t)|$; If I put, $\frac{x}{t}=y$, then $\partial^{n}\phi(y)= ?$, I don't know how to handle, from here; thanks)

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $x$, we have
 $$(1+|x|)^m|\partial^n\phi_t(x)|=t^{-(n+1)}(1+|x|^m)(\partial^n\phi)(x/t)
=t^{-(n+1)}(1+t^m|x/t|^m)|(\partial^n\phi)(x/t)|\\
\leqslant t^{-(n+1)}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R}(1+t^m|y|^m)|\partial^n\phi(y)|.$$
To conclude, notice that $1+t^my^m\leqslant (1+t^m)(1+|y|^m)$, hence 
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}(1+|x|)^m|\partial^n\phi_t(x)|\leqslant 
 (1+t^m)t^{-(n+1)}\sup_{y\in\mathbb R}(1+t^m|y|^m)|\partial^n\phi(y)|<+\infty.$$